# next, previous based on current sort order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scopes

I have scopes defined in an include module like this:

```
module ActsAsAdjacent

  def self.included(base)

    base.send(:scope, :next, lambda {|id| {:conditions => ["id > ?",id],
       :order => "id ASC", :limit => 1}}) 

    base.send(:scope, :previous, lambda {|id| {:conditions => ["id < ?",id],
       :order => "id DESC", :limit => 1}})     
  end
```

But actually I want it so it does next, previous not based on some specific column, but instead on whatever the current sort order is, so for example if

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  default_scope :order => 'users.name ASC'

  include ActsAsAdjacent
```

then ActsAsAdjacent would automatically use name instead.

Actually, if there were a method that returned the offset of the current ActiveRecord object that would solve my problem. But the offset that exists only *sets* the offset of returned records.